# Error in updating the description of a subtask in rails using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I Have a app where in i am creating task and subtasks under those tasks.These new subtasks are created using ajax,so that i do not need to refresh the page.So now every subtask also has a bootstrap modal associated with it.The modal has a description form,which updates the description field of subtask.

The problem is that all the subtasks which are created throuh ajax,their description i am not able to update,i am getting an error sayin no route matches subtasks/:id,but when i refresh the page and do the same thing again,it works.

I am not able to figure out why is this happening.

Here is the code subtasks/descform

```
         <%=subtask.description %><br>
                 <a data-id='<%=subtask.id %>' href="#" id='editdesc_<%=subtask.id %>'>Edit description...</a>
                  <div class="subtaskdescform" id="subtaskdesform_<%=subtask.id %>">
                  <%=form_for subtask,:remote=>:true,:method => :put do |f| %>
                  <%= f.text_area :description,rows:'5',cols:'12',:class=>'myarea'%>
                  <%= f.submit "save",class:'btn btn-success col-md-4' %>
                  <a data-id='<%=subtask.id %>' href="#" class="myclose"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" style="margin:10px auto;"></i></a>
                  <% end %>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                  $('.mydes > a').click(function(e){
          $('#subtaskdesform_' + $(this).data('id')).show(1000);
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.myclose').click(function(e){


          $('#subtaskdesform_'+ $(this).data('id')).hide(1000);
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        </script>



                </div>
```

Here is the update.js code

$('#mydes_'+ <%=@subtask.id %>).html('<%=j(render partial: "subtasks/descform",locals: {subtask: @subtask})%>');

Here is my update action

```
              def update

    @subtask=Subtask.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @subtask.update_attribute(:description,params[:subtask][:description])
            format.html{redirect_to @project}
            format.js
        else
            render new
        end
    end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your form's method "PUT":

```
form_for subtask, :remote=>:true, :method => :put
```

I think you have to review routes. It appears that in routes subtask's method is "GET" but in form you are requesting "PUT". Check subtask path method using:

```
rake routes
```

Change :method => :put to :get

Comment: I actually figured out the solution,it was coz of some ajax issue.Solved it and its working fine now.Anyways thanks for ur help